# Cannot use the export of an ambient module as type annotation in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, js-amd

I am writing a TypeScript Type definition for a pretty large (800+ files) AMD JavaScript library.  Below you can see a snippet:

```
declare namespace myjslib {
  namespace shape {
    interface Shape {
      contains(p: Point): boolean;
    }

    class Point implements Shape {
      constructor(x: number, y: number);
      contains(p: Point): boolean;
    }

    class Circle implements Shape {
      constructor(p: Point, radius: number);
      contains(p: Point): boolean;
    }
  }
}

declare module "myjslib/shape/Point" {
  export = myjslib.shape.Point;
}

declare module "myjslib/shape/Circle" {
  export = myjslib.shape.Circle;
}
```

I have defined types in namespaces.  (note that myjslib is not the real name of the library :)):

- The namespaces pretty much correspond with the module IDs in the AMD library, as you can see from the module declarations.
- I decided to put these classes into namespaces to avoid clashes (cfr. 
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html). Class names like `Point` and `Circle` are likely to clash if my library is combined with other JavaScript libraries.

I then try to write a TypeScript application that depends on this type definition file:

```
/// <reference path="./myjslib.d.ts" />
import Point = require("myjslib/shape/Point");
import Circle = require("myjslib/shape/Circle");

import Circ = myjslib.shape.Circle;

let c1 = new Circle(new Point(1,3), 20);
let c2: Circle;
let c3: myjslib.shape.Circle;
let c4: Circ;

c1.contains(new Point(5,6));
c2 = c1;
c3 = c1;
c4 = c1;
```

When compiling this typescript file, the correct JavaScript code is generated:  the output is valid AMD, can be loaded with an off the shelf AMD module loader, and can be optimized into a single JavaScript file, etc.

However, the TypeScript compiler generates an error at the declaration of the `c2` variable:

```
>tsc --module amd app.ts
app.ts(8,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Circle'.
```

Apparently, it is possible to refer to the imported `Circle` to create a circle. the import statement works as you have access to the `Circle` constructor.  However, `Circle` cannot be used as a type annotation when declaring a variable of that type.  What is also possible is using the fully qualified name of the type:  the compiler does not complain about the `c3` declaration, so the typescript definition file is found and used by the compiler.  Also, if I create an alias `Circ`, The type system works like a charm (declaration of `c4`).

It was my understanding that the `import Circle = require("myjslib/shape/Circle")` statement imported the type information as well.  To use the terminology in [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html), I would expect `Circle` to be available in the type declaration space in that module, but it is not.  The type information is loaded through the TypeScript definition file though: the `myjslib` namespace is available.

So in conclusion: I have to write code where I have to use the import to create instances of a particular class, but I have to use the fully qualified type name if I want to declare variables of that class.  This makes writing code pretty confusing (and verbose).  Is there any way around this?  Is this the expected behavior, or am I running into a TypeScript compiler bug?